# AddPackageByAppInstallerFileAsync exception - file not found

Tags: c#, msix, appinstaller

I am trying to follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/non-store-developer-updates#updating-packages-deployed-using-an-app-installer-file) to update my app (winforms app bundled in an MSIX package) via code.
My package is published to a network share along with the .appinstaller file.
Manually installing/updating from the .appinstaller works fine, and letting Windows update at startup works fine too.
But when I try to initiate the update via code, I get an `SEHException` "External component has thrown an exception".  The error code is -2147467259, which I believe is some kind of "file not found" error.  Here's my code:

```
var pm = new PackageManager();
await pm.AddPackageByAppInstallerFileAsync(Package.Current.GetAppInstallerInfo().Uri,
          AddPackageByAppInstallerOptions.ForceTargetAppShutdown,             
          pm.GetDefaultPackageVolume());
```

I've ensured the value of `Package.Current.GetAppInstallerInfo().Uri` is correct - pasting the value into the Run dialog launches the installer.

Is there an issue with hosting the package on a share drive?  Or am I doing something else wrong?

Edit: I've also tried publishing to a website and get the same error.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet ? I have th exact same problem

Comment: @keytrap Nope, we ended up not using MSIX.